# Core Data: update child context

Tags: ios, core-data, ios8

If I have one NSManagedObjectContext and two children of it, one for updating in background from web service (A) and other for operations in the UI thread (B) the question is:
How the NSManagedObjectContext B is notified about changes in the parent managed object context once the background context (A) has been updated with new information and save it to the parent context?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand right, you can observe the DidSaveNotification from you context B. Like this:

```
self.observer = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
    NSManagedObjectContext *notMoc = [note object];
    if (![weakSelf.managedObjectContext isEqual:notMoc]) {
        [weakSelf.managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
            [weakSelf.managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:note];
        }];
    }
}];
```

Comment: If you're using MagicalRecord, [context MR_observeContext:other] will do this for you